# simpleXML script

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to make a simple script which has to convert a PHP array to XML.. but I can't make it work.. The script works fine when the array only has one dimension and when there are more dimensions all nodes are appended to the "root" node

```
#class
    class XML {
        private $root = '<response />';

        function __construct($root=null){
            $this->root = new SimpleXMLElement($root ? $root:$this->root);
        }

        function encode($arr, $node=null){
            $node = $node ? $node:$this->root;
            foreach($arr as $key => $value){
                if(is_array($value)){
                    $this->encode($value, $node->addChild($key));
                }
                else{
                    $node->addChild($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }

        function output(){
            return $this->root->asXML();
        }
    }


#code

    $arr = array(
        'test' => 'noget',
        'hmmm' => 12,
        'arr' => array(
            99 => 'haha',
            'arr2' => array(
                ),
            'dd' => '333'
            )
        );
    print_r($arr);
    require_once '../class/class.XML.php';
    $XML = new XML();
    $XML->encode($arr);
    echo $XML->output();

#output

    Array
    (
        [test] => noget
        [hmmm] => 12
        [arr] => Array
            (
                [99] => haha
                [arr2] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dd] => 333
            )

    )
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <response><test>noget</test><hmmm>12</hmmm><arr/><99>haha</99><arr2/><dd>333</dd></response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code looks quite fine to do what you want it to do, however, you must more carefully check for the optional `$node` parameter in:

```
function encode($arr, $node=null){
    $node = $node ? $node:$this->root;
```

I could get it to working like so:

```
function encode($arr, $node=null){
    $node = null === $node ? $this->root : $node;
```

An empty simplexml element is `false` ([see the last point in this *Converting to boolean* list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) and as you add an empty child it's always false and you added again to the root element.